# how to call files in child theme?

Tags: child-theme

I created a child theme **"my-theme"** . In style.css I wrote nothing just the mandatory details I wrote there.

```
/*
Theme Name:     my-theme
Theme URI:      http://example.com/
Description:    Child theme for the Twenty Twelve theme 
Author:         Bhuvnesh
Author URI:     http://example.com/about/
Template:       my-theme
Version:        0.1.0
*/
```

All the style rules I am writting in **"my-theme/css/style.css"** file. Now in **index.php** I am calling **`<?php get_header(); ?>`** this will call **header.php** now in **header.php** file I am calling that css file as

`<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

but this is not loading my css. same like this I am calling some **.js** files which are under **"my-theme/js/"** directory as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
```

this is also not loading.

I know I am making some mistakes to call files or may be in functions.php .

I just copied the full file **functions.php**  of **twentytwelve** . Is there any mistake I am doing ?

Please tell me what to write in **functions.php** file and how to call files like js files under js directory .php files under includes directory , images under Images directory.

I searched how to create child theme and it's done but unable to call files.

Please Help me!I will be very thankful to you!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One does not simply throw `<link>` (CSS) or `<script>` tags into the `<head>` of a WordPress theme.

### The right way to do it: Register, enqueue ... tadaa!

WordPress has the "Dependency API" for this task. It consists basically out of those public functions:

- [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [`wp_register_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)
- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Then there're aligning functions to [deregister scripts or styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script), get data [from PHP to JS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) - for example to use them for localization or AJAX calls - and [checks/Conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is) to see if a style or script was registered/enqueued.

### How to use them

First, you need to make sure that your `header.php` file has the appropriate hook:

```
wp_head();
```

Then add function to your themes `functions.php` file, like explained [on WP Make](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/). As you can see, both scripts and files, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts`-hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse82474_load_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse82474_load_scripts' );
wpse82474_load_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( /* etc. */ );
}
wpse82474_load_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( /* etc. */ );
}
```

### The arguments

The main arguments are the following

```
 wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

In the real world (to speak: In your theme), you'll use it like the following. The examples shows a script that has `jQuery` loaded as dependency (in other words: loaded before your enqueued file).

```
wp_enqueue_script(
     'my-theme-script'
    ,get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom_script.js'
    ,array( 'jquery' )
);
```

### Getting the path right

From within a childtheme you'd always want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and from within a parent or "normal" theme, you'd use `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Loading from a subfolder of your child theme would use a path like this:

```
$stylesheet_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/style.css';
```

### Loading WP scripts & styles shipped with core

In case you want to load files that are already shipped with core, then you can simply enqueue them without and further arguments.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // Load jQuery
```

The same goes for each and every other [script (or style) shipped with core, as you can read in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress).

If you want to know if a script is already registered, there's no need to look in core or search in Codex. Simply use [`wp_script_is()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) (or it's equivalent for styles). Per default this checks the `enqueue` list, but you can also use `registered` or `done` as arguments.

```
wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'registered' ) AND wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Answer (score 4):

All your included js and css files are included using relative paths. This is bad.

You'll find that the use of a child theme is irrelevant, as it is horribly broken with and without a child theme.

So instead, learn to enqueue styles and scripts properly using `wp_enqueue_style` in functions.php

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
  // Register the style like this for a theme:  
  // (First the unique name for the style (custom-style) then the src, 
  // then dependencies and ver no. and media type)
  wp_register_style( 'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', 
    array(), 
    '20120208', 
    'all' );

  // enqueing:
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

and `wp_enqueue_script`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Final notes:

- Never include scripts and styles directly in header.php
- Always use wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script
- If you don't use those functions, caching plugins cannot modify them and you miss out on things
- Never bundle JQuery in your theme, always use the copy that came via WordPress, nevermind bundling a version as outdated as v1.7.x

Answer (score 0):

In the `style.css` file of your child theme, you have a line `Template: my-theme`. This should be the name of the template you want to have as parent.

An example for a child theme of the default Twenty Twelve theme:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Twenty Twelve Child
Theme URI:      http://example.com/
Description:    Child theme for the Twenty Twelve theme 
Author:         Your name here
Author URI:     http://example.com/about/
Template:       twentytwelve
Version:        0.1.0
*/
```

> A quick explanation of each line:
>
> - Theme Name. (required) Child theme name.
> - Theme URI. (optional) Child theme webpage.
> - Description. (optional) What this theme is. E.g.: My first child theme. Hurrah!
> - Author. (optional) Author name.
> - Author URI. (optional) Author webpage.
> - Template. (required) directory name of parent theme, case-sensitive.
>
>   - NOTE. You have to switch to a different theme and back to the child theme when you modify this line.
> - Version. (optional) Child theme version. E.g.: 0.1, 1.0, etc.

More information about child themes you can find [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in the Codex pages.

This way you shouldn't have any problems anymore with child theme files that won't load.