# enqueue script if page is not equal to

Tags: theme-development, functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm registering some js scripts in my function.php, I have 2 versions of one js file, one FOR the homepage, and one for every other page.
I've managed to get this to work to register the homepage script successfully:

```
function home_script_method() {
    wp_register_script( 'homescript', '/wp-content/themes/template/js/menu-home-open.js' );
    if( !is_page( 'home' ) ) // If it's not the given page, stop here
    return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'homescript' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'home_script_method' );
```

But is it at all possible to register an alternative script for every other page, i.e. if on the homepage then register `menu-home-open.js`, if on any other page then register `menu-open.js`. Is that at all possible? Can't seem to get it to work, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82474/how-to-call-files-in-child-theme/82498#82498) and this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/385), then edit your code :)

Comment: @kaiser quite right, edited, cheers for that. That better? :)

Comment: Take a look at your callback. Afaik there should be an argument/variable that you can dump: `home_script_method( $arg ) { var_dump( $arg );`, but I'm not sure right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ron_scripts' );
function ron_scripts(){
   if(is_home()){
     wp_register_script( 'homescript', '/wp-content/themes/template/js/menu-home-open.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'homescript' );
     } else {
     wp_register_script( 'nothomescript', '/wp-content/themes/template/js/FILENAMEHERE.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'nothomescript' );
    }
}
```

alternatively replace `is_home();` with any other method or code that determines what page you are on. ex:

might work

```
if(site_url() == get_permalink()){
  //do home stuff
} else {
  //do not home stuff
}
```